# Find the largest value of a series based on values in a different range in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two scenarios, the ideal situation is when the data is spread across cells in a worksheet and I need to find all cells that match a certain value then take all values from the matches and return largest in the set.

To help me figure out how to do this, I created a helper table that takes all of the relevant values and tries to solve this problem and I still can't get it to work.

```
$G$18 = G

3   B
7   D
5   E
12  G
6   G
7   H
4   H
```

So, in column B, I need to find all duplicate values and based on those values return the largest corresponding value from the set in column A.

Here's the formula I was working with that is not returning what I am expecting. I've carved this several different ways and still don't get the result I expect. If I search for all G values, for instance, I want to return 12 as the result.

```
={INDEX(Table1[A],LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$18,Table1[B])),ROW($A$3:$A$53)-ROW($A$3)+1),1))}
```

I get the value 6, when I should get 12.

[image]

Any hints or suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Max with If entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> as an array formula

```
=MAX(IF(B2:B8=F19,A2:A8))
```

You should see curly braces appear around the formula.

---

**Data:**

[image: Data]

Comment: I would love some input on the scenario directly because the obvious solution does not work for my scenario. Reducing the set into these two columns works, but it does not solve my problem and I'm still stuck trying to make it work.